# InvalidValueError: in property origin: not a string in google map

Tags: google-maps, compiler-errors, google-maps-markers, marker

I have a application where i have to plot the polylines and place some markers on the google map where in order to plot the polylines i am getting the data from the database every thing works fine but i am getting the error in developers console has 
InvalidValueError: in property origin: not a string; and not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: not an Object; and not an Object

After trying to debug for a long time i found there is some problem in the way plot the polyline (ie some undefined value is pumbing in the array please have a  look in the for loop )

```
for (var i = 0; i <lat_lng.length+2; i++) {
      var src = lat_lng[i];
      var des = lat_lng[i + 1];
      var k=i;
      i=i+1;
      getDirections(src, des, colorVariable[k%colorVariable.length], map);
    }
```

this is angularjs application my complete controller is has shown below

//....map controller.........

```
changiControllers.controller("map", function ($scope,$http) {
  $(".calendarMain .selectDay").dateSelectSlider();
  $(".timeSlider").timeSlider();
  $scope.jsonData=[ {
    "title": 'point11',
    "lat": '1.351477',
    "lng": '103.985701',
    "description": 'uuu'
  }, {
    "title": 'point12',
    "lat": '1.350265',
    "lng": '103.985165',
    "description": 'uuu'
  }];
  $scope.markerData=[{
    "title": 'point3',
    "lat": '1.354432',
    "lng": '103.987262',
    "description": 'zzz'
  }];
  socket.on('plotData', function (dataMap) {
    $scope.jsonData=[];
    $scope.markerData=[];
    for(var i = 0;i<dataMap.data.length;i++){
      if(i==3||i==6){
        $scope.markerData.push(dataMap.data[i]);
      }
      $scope.jsonData.push(dataMap.data[i]);
    }
    $scope.$apply();
    $scope.laneMapInit();
  });


  $scope.laneMapInit=function() {
    var gmarkers = [];
    var colorVariable = ["yellow", "green", "red"];
    var map;
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(1.35, 103.987),
      zoom: 17,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      scrollwheel: true,
      draggable: true,
      disableDefaultUI: false,
      heading: 90,
      tilt: 0,
      styles: [
        {
          "featureType": "poi",
          "stylers": [
            { "visibility": "off" }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("laneMap"), mapOptions);
    var data= $scope.jsonData;
    var lat_lng = new Array();
    var markerModel= $scope.markerData;
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    for ( var a = 0; a < data.length; a++) {
      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data[a].lat, data[a].lng);
      lat_lng.push(myLatlng);
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < markerModel.length; j++) {
      var myLatlngMarker = new google.maps.LatLng(markerModel[j].lat, markerModel[j].lng);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlngMarker,
        map: map,
        icon: {
          url:'images/liveCam32.png',
        },
        title: markerModel[j].title
      });
      latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);
      (function(marker, markerModel) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
          infoWindow.setContent(markerModel.description);
          infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });
      })(marker, markerModel[j]);
      gmarkers.push(marker);
    }
    map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());

    for (var i = 0; i <lat_lng.length+2; i++) {
      var src = lat_lng[i];
      var des = lat_lng[i + 1];
      var k=i;
      i=i+1;
      getDirections(src, des, colorVariable[k%colorVariable.length], map);
    }
    function getDirections(src, des, color, map) {
      //Intialize the Direction Service
      var service = new google.maps.DirectionsService( {preserveViewport: true} );
      service.route({
        origin: src,
        destination: des,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
      }, function(result, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          //Intialize the Path Array
          var path = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < result.routes[0].overview_path.length; i++) {
            path.push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i]);
          }
          //Set the Path Stroke Color
          var polyOptions = {
            strokeColor: color,
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 8,
            path: path,
            map: map
          }
          poly = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
          poly.setMap(map);

        }
      });
    }
  };

  $scope.laneMapInit();

  $scope.simulateMapDraw = function(flag){
    if(flag){
      $scope.mapPlotIntervalId=setInterval(function() {
        $http.get('http://localhost:3000/newPlotMsg').then(function(result){
        });
      },4000);
    }else if(!flag){
      clearInterval($scope.mapPlotIntervalId);
    }
  }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are running past the end of your array.  `i` can't be equal to or greater than `lat_lng.length`, change:

```
for (var i = 0; i <lat_lng.length+2; i++) {
  var src = lat_lng[i];
  var des = lat_lng[i + 1];
  var k=i;
  i=i+1;
  getDirections(src, des, colorVariable[k%colorVariable.length], map);
}
```

To:

```
for (var i = 0; i < lat_lng.length; i++) {
  var src = lat_lng[i];
  var des = lat_lng[i + 1];
  var k=i;
  i=i+1;
  getDirections(src, des, colorVariable[k%colorVariable.length], map);
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/8zcux6d5/1/)

Comment: thank you i tried debugging by removed the +2 in for loop but still i am getting the same error in the console can u please share your skype id so that can help me explain the problem more clearly please share it that would be great help

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue and a clear description of the problem **in your question**.

Comment: yes it fixed the error but the markers which has to be placed on the map is not displayed now after the change the behavior of the map became unpredictable

Comment: If this solved the question you asked, then you should accept it and do some research on your new problem, if you can't find an answer, create a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits it, then ask another question about it.